# Apply the same surgical fix onto the two very different branches

Tags: git

Let's say I have `branch_a` branched out of `master` a month ago. Both branches are very different now, and are a month away from being merged...

Let's say I discovered a small bug that can be fixed by changing the same same 3 lines of code in both branches. The fix need to be in both branches ASAP.

Other than checking out `master` and `branch_a` separately, and making the the same fix twice -- is there a way to apply the same 3-line fix to both branches?  I mean... I cannot make the fix in one one branch and then merge it to the other branch - it'll contaminate it with everything else I do not wish to merge yet.

any hack/trick/method to do that?

Comment: `git cherry-pick`? Basically make the change and commit to one branch, then cherry-pick that commit onto the other branch too

Comment: yeah, git  cherry-pick would be nice :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to merge either branch into the other, then here's what you want to do:

1. Create a third branch off of the commit where the two branches diverged.
2. Commit the bug fix to the new branch.
3. Merge the new branch into each of the other branches.

If you cherry-pick, that is basically doing what you said you didn't want to do...checking out each branch separately and making the fix two times.  This way, you only have one commit and you have a clean history of how that one commit made it into both branches.

@Liam is right in what he says in the comment.  This is how a "hot fix" branch is created and used in a standard [Git Flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) pipeline.  One thing that is a bit different here is that you have commits in your "master" branch that aren't already in your other branch(es).  This is never the case in the classic Git Flow pipeline.

Comment: hmmm go back in time and merge out at the earliest point where the two branches were identical. not bad. thanks!

Comment: FYI, this is essentially what's called a [hotfix branch in GIT flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)

Comment: @Liam - thanks for the tip.  If you saw my earlier comment, I had somehow got in my head that neither of the branches is the "master" branch, even though the OP clearly says that one of them is.  Once I saw that, I went back and rethought your comment, and you were absolutely correct.